# Add animation in element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a simple app, that transfers an element inside an element.
So I have 2 set of shapes, square and circle. First I have to choose a circle and then a square, the moment I click on a square, the circle that I chose will be move inside the square. the code is working fine, its just, I have to add animation like the circle is moving inside the square I choose.

Hope you understand me.

Thanks

[**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/NBNLyW)

```js
$('.circle').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  var selected = $(this);

  $('.container .square').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).html(selected);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 230px;
  width: 110px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.round {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}

.square .circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle.selected {
  background-color: #FFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="round">
    <div class="circle">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to add the animation from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) my problem is the direction is irregular, I cant move the element specially in diagonal direction

Comment: This is not something CSS should be able to do, but can be achieved with JavaScript. I added a working answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your looking for something like the snippet below.

The problem is that you don't know where your circle is and to what square it must go. The `$selected.offset()` is the position of the element on the screen and with the `position: fixed` it places the circle on the screen at the same position it was on.

Then the animation makes sure to animate the circle from it's new position, to the position of the square on the screen (hence the `$this.offset`, which is the position of the square).

```js
var $body = $('body'),
    $selected;

$('.round .circle').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $selected = $(this);
});

$('.container .square').click(function(){
  if ($selected) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $selected.css({
      top: $selected.offset().top,
      left: $selected.offset().left,
      position: 'absolute'
    }).appendTo($body).animate({
      top: $this.offset().top + 2,
      left: $this.offset().left + 2
    }, 1000, function() {
      $(this).css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 'auto',
        left: 'auto',
      }).appendTo($this);
    });
    
    $this.addClass('selected');
  }
  
  $selected = undefined;
});
```

```css
.container{
  height: 300px;
  width: 110px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}
.round{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}
.square{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}
.square .circle{
    position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.circle span{
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.circle.selected{
  background-color: #FFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="box">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
 <div class="round">
   <div class="circle">
     <span>1</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>2</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>3</span>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">
     <span>4</span>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some thoughts:

After ending the animation, you could add the element to the square again and remove the temporary styling (the top, left and position). But I think you're able to do that :)

Comment: Here is an alternative : https://codepen.io/TMLN/pen/zLqMRx because the solution Douwe de Haan proposed follows the user scrolling since the element has a fixed position

Comment: @Mark Thomas is right. I forgot about scrolling. If I have some time today I will update my answer to make sure it works anywhere on a page!

Comment: @Mark I updated my code. It should now work with pages that scroll!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@keyframes` in css transition I've got example below its not yet optimize or i mean implemented properly but you can see how it works. thanks alot.

```js
$('.circle').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  var selected = $(this);

  $('.container .square').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $(this).html(selected);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 230px;
  width: 110px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.round {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.square {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #f60;
  position: relative;
}

.square .circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle span {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle.selected {
  background-color: #FFFF;
  animation: fuckingmove 5s; 
}

@keyframes fuckingmove {
  from {top: 200px;}
  to {top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="round">
    <div class="circle">
      <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <span>4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice keyframe name